# Separation of term in Møller scattering cross section

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, spinors, scattering-cross-section

In trying to calculate the Møller scattering cross section, I arrived at the following term$^1$:
$$\frac{e^4}{(p_3-p_1)^4}\bar u(p_3)\gamma^\mu u(p_1)\bar u(p_4)\gamma_\mu u(p_2)\bar u(p_2)\gamma_\nu u(p_4)\bar u(p_1)\gamma^\nu u(p_3),$$
where $p_1,p_2$ are the incoming momenta and $p_3,p_4$ are the outgoing momenta.
In QFT in a nutshell, Zee separates this term like this$^2$:
$$\frac{e^4}{(p_3-p_1)^4}[\bar u(p_3)\gamma^\mu u(p_1)\bar u(p_1)\gamma^\nu u(p_3)][\bar u(p_4)\gamma_\mu u(p_2)\bar u(p_2)\gamma_\nu u(p_4)].$$
I don't understand how he arrived at this. What relations am I missing?

---

$^1$ Spin polarizations have been omitted.

$^2$ The original notation is $p_1,p_2$ for incoming momenta, $P_1,P_2$ for outgoing momenta and $k\equiv(p_3-p_1)$.

Comment: "*I don't understand how he arrived at this.*" By the same principle that allows you to write $AB=(A)(B)$ for any pair of complex numbers $A$ and $B$.

Comment: $\bar{u}$ is a row vector, $u$ is a column vector, and in-between you have matrices, everything with dimension 4. Make sense now?

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis Got it! $\bar u\gamma^\mu u$ is a scalar, so the above expression can be separated as 4 scalars and these can be rearranged to Zee's expression. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Luc points in the comments, $\bar u, u$ are row and column vectors, so  $\bar u 
\gamma^\mu u$ is a scalar. Thus the expression may be arranged this way:
$$\frac{e^4}{(p_3-p_1)^4}\underbrace{[\bar u(p_3)\gamma^\mu u(p_1)]}_1\underbrace{[\bar u(p_4)\gamma_\mu u(p_2)]}_2\underbrace{[\bar u(p_2)\gamma_\nu u(p_4)]}_3\underbrace{[\bar u(p_1)\gamma^\nu u(p_3)]}_4.$$
Changing the order  from $1234$ to $1423$ gives Zee's result.

---

**Edit:** As @JamalS points out, $\bar u, u $ carry spinor indices and $\gamma^\mu$ a Lorentz index, so $\bar u\gamma^\mu u$ is a scalar with respect to spinor indices only.

Comment: $u$ and $\bar u$ are spinors, so they carry $\alpha,\beta$ indices, just as when we write $\gamma^\mu$ we mean $(\gamma^\mu)_{\alpha\beta}$. Two spinors with one $\gamma^\mu$ soaks up the two spinor indices, but we still have the Lorentz index. So while you can swap them safely, strictly speaking the factor on its own is not a scalar unless you are more specific with regards to what it is a scalar with respect to.

Comment: @JamalS You're right. I edited the answer to be more precise. Thank you.